# Summation of product of $m+1$ alternate numbers

Tags: summation

We know that 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n \prod_{j=0}^m (r+j)&=\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+m)\\
&=(m+1)!\sum_{r=1}^n\binom {r+m}{m+1}\\
&=(m+1)!\binom {n+m+1}{m+2}\\
&=\frac {(n+m+1)^\underline{m+2}}{m+2}\end{align}$$
but is there a similar closed form for 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \prod_{j=0}^m (r+2j)=\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+2)(r+4)\cdots (r+2m)$$
?

---

*Edit 1*

Here's a summary of results from wolframlpha for the first few values of $m$ (please excuse the messy alignment).

[image]

From the summary we observe some interesting patterns as follows:

- all results have factors $n,(n+1)$
- all results have a factor of $\frac 1{2(m+2)}$ or $\frac 1{m+2}$ where the product of the other factors results in a $2n^{m+2}$ term or $n^{m+2}$ term respectively
- for $m=2$: $(n+4),(n+5)$ are factors
- for $m=4$: $(n+8),(n+9)$ are factors
- for $m=6$: $(n+12),(n+13)$ are factors
- for $m=8$: $(n+16),(n+17)$ are factors
- this implies that for even $m$: $(n+2m), (n+2m+1)$ are factors

Perhaps the observations above might be helpful in working out the solution.

The solution could then possibly be of the form:

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac {n(n+1)(n+2m)(n+2m+1)\cdot f(n,m)}{2(m+2)}\qquad \text{for even $m$}\\
\dfrac {n(n+1)\cdot g(n,m)}{2(m+2)}\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text {for odd $m$}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+2)(r+4)...(r+2m)&=\sum_{1\le r=2k\le n}r(r+2)(r+4)...(r+2m)\\&+\sum_{1\le r=2k+1\le n}r(r+2)(r+4)...(r+2m) \\ &=\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(2k+2m)!!}{(2k-2)!!}}_{S_1}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(2k+2m+1)!!}{(2k-1)!!}}_{S_2}\end{align*}

where: $\quad (2x)!!=2^x .x!\quad $ and $\quad (2x-1)!!=\dfrac{(2x)!}{(2x)!!}$

Note that: $\quad 0!!=2^0.0!=\frac{0!}{0!!}=(-1)!!=1$

\begin{align*} S_1&=(2m+2)!!+\frac{1}{2m+4}\sum_{k=2}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\Delta\left(\frac{(2m+2k)!!}{(2k-4)!!}\right)\\ &=(2m+2)!!+\frac{1}{2m+4}\cdot\frac{\left(2m+2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+2\right)!!}{\left(2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)!!}-\frac{1}{2m+4}\cdot\frac{(2m+4)!!}{0!!}\\&=\frac{1}{2m+4}\cdot\frac{\left(2m+2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+2\right)!!}{\left(2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-2\right)!!}\end{align*}

\begin{align*} S_2&=(2m+1)!!+\frac{1}{2m+4}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\Delta\left(\frac{(2m+2k+1)!!}{(2k-3)!!}\right)\\ &=(2m+1)!!+\frac{1}{2m+4}\cdot\frac{\left(2m+2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)!!}{\left(2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor-3\right)!!}-\frac{1}{2m+4}\cdot\frac{(2m+3)!!}{(-1)!!}\\&=\frac{(2m+1)!!}{2m+4}+\frac{1}{2m+4}\cdot\frac{\left(2m+2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)!!}{\left(2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor-3\right)!!}\end{align*}

Comment: $n$ must satify condition $ n\ge 2 $

Comment: (+1) for the diligent effort! Looks like quite a complex result. Would it be possible to state it as only one term rather than as a sum of three?

Comment: what a charm and elegance

Comment: @hxthanh - please see additional points under Edit 1 in the original question.... would you be able to formulate your solution in the form described?

Comment: Yes, I see. I m trying to closed form... Wait for me

Answer (score 1):

Simply for my result, I have:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\prod_{j=0}^m(r+2j)=S(n,m)=\frac{1}{2m+4}\left(\prod_{k=0}^m(2k+1)+\prod_{k=0}^{m+1}(n+2k)+\prod_{k=0}^{m+1}(n+2k-1)\right)$$

That's a polynomial of $n$ with $m+2$ degrees.

The first few values of $m$
\begin{align*}S(n,1)&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\prod_{k=0}^1(2k+1)+\prod_{k=0}^2(n+2k)+\prod_{k=0}^2(n+2k-1)\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{6}\bigg(1.3+n(n+2)(n+4)+(n-1)(n+1)(n+3)\bigg)\\ &=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+7)\end{align*}
\begin{align*}S(n,2)&=\frac{1}{8}\bigg(1.3.5+n(n+2)(n+4)(n+6)+(n-1)(n+1)(n+3)(n+5)\bigg) \\ &=\frac{1}{8}\cdot2n(n+1)(n+4)(n+5)\end{align*}

etc..,

I think so don't closed form for this sum, It is a similarity with the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^r$

Comment: For $n=0$ or $n=-1$ then $S(0,m)=S(-1,m)=0$
For $n=-2m$ or $n=-2m-1$ then $\displaystyle S(-2m,m)=S(-2m-1,m)=\dfrac{1+(-1)^{m+1}}{2m+4}\prod_{k=0}^m (2k+1)$
Therefore all your comments are true!

Comment: Thanks for the new post and the comment confirming my earlier observations (+1). Re your comment that there is no closed form and the similarity with $\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$, would it then be possible to state the sum using Faulhabner's formula or any other variant of it?